# how can I get pyodbc to perform a "SELECT ... INTO" statement without locking?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to copy a table in SQL Server, but a simple statement seems to be locking my database when using pyodbc. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
dbCxn = db.connect(cxnString)
dbCursor = dbCxn.cursor()
query = """\
SELECT TOP(10) *
INTO production_data_adjusted
FROM production_data
"""
dbCursor.execute(query)
```

The last statement returns immediately, but both LINQPad and SQL Server Management Studio are locked out of the database afterwards (I try to refresh their table lists). Running `sp_who2` shows that LINQPad/SSMS are stuck waiting for my pyodbc process. Other databases on the server seem fine, but all access to this database gets held up. The only way I can get these other applications to resolve their stalls is by closing the pyodbc database connection:

```
dbCxn.close()
```

This exact same `SELECT ... INTO` statement statement works fine and takes only a second from LINQPad and SSMS. The above code works fine and *doesn't* lock the database if I remove the `INTO` line. It even returns results if I add `fetchone()` or `fetchall()`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the commit function of either the [cursor](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#commit) or [connection](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#commit) after `SELECT ... INTO` is executed, for example:

```
...
dbCursor.execute(query)
dbCursor.commit()
```

Alternatively, automatic commit of transactions can be specified when the connection is created using [autocommit](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#autocommit). Note that `autocommit` is an argument to the [connect](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) function, not a connection string attribute, for example:

```
...
dbCxn = db.connect(cxnString, autocommit=True)
...
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Maybe I missed some bit of documentation on this originally.